# Explode() is not exploding the string at the specified character in PHP

Tags: php, html, explode

I have a php script that takes a persons full name as a string from a drop down menu, and is supposed to explode it on a space.

```
$fullName = $_GET["nameList"];
$nameArray = explode(" ", $fullName);
```

When I var_dump() the array, the entire string, with the space, is contained in the first element.

```
[0]=> string(11) "First Last"
```

I used ctype_print() to see if there are any non printable characters in the string that it would need to separate on instead of a space, but it's showing that all characters in the string are printable.

Comment: This is the second question like this I have seen in a couple of days. What OS and what version of PHP are you using please

Comment: Works for me: https://repl.it/repls/RequiredUncomfortableArtificialintelligence

Comment: Can you `var_dump()` on `$_GET['nameList']`? it might be a tab `\t` instead of a space

Comment: I'm running PHP 7.2.2 on a Windows 2016 Server

Comment: Does `$nameArray = preg_split('/\s+/', $fullName);` produce the correct array?

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump(array_map(function($val){ return ord($val); }, preg_split('//', $fullName)));` Item 6 should be   `int(32)`

Comment: Is the space a space? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

Comment: as @mike.k said `preg_split` is the way to go. `\s` covers all kinds of whitespace.

Comment: @mplungjan, that would be my guess too. The string length of 11 is also consistent with a non breaking space: https://3v4l.org/KrbVb